# how to call google Resources.calendars api from python.

Tags: python, api, calendar, resources

I am not able to find python script to call google Resources.calendars list method. 
I can see the details on how to call using GET method but not from python.

https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/resources/calendars/list

Please help me on this.

Comment: Why would calling it from Python be any different from calling it from anything else, or different from calling any other endpoint?

Comment: Looking for the method something similar to the below:https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/quickstart/python.

in this script they have given users.list method. But I want to know what is it for resources.calendars : list method

Answer (score 0):

try this: 
results = calendarService.events().list(calendarId='my_customer', timeMin = start_date, timeMax = end_date).execute()